# google colab with google cloud storage data egress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, gcsfuse

[image]

I'm trying to teach my network on data that is stored in google cloud storage. I'm teaching using google colab pro resources and when I do that, I got around 50$ bill a day for "egress between NA and EU". I'm located in Russia and data storage is in Germany so I have absolutely no idea why this data egress to NA. How can I stop this behavior and why does it happen, because I don't want to pay for something I don't really need.

Link between storage and colab looks like this:

```
#downloading gcsfuse
!echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
!curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
!apt -qq update
!apt -qq install gcsfuse
#Mounting Raw folder
!mkdir raw
!gcsfuse -o nonempty raw-images-dng-storage /content/raw 

#Mounting tiff folder
!mkdir tiff
!gcsfuse -o nonempty expert-c-images-tiff /content/tiff
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Colab server is run in USA (North America).

So, to avoid network cost, you should host your gcs bucket in USA as well (instead of Germany).

Comment: What if I will use local runtime?

Comment: @Saffer "For now, Colab Pro is only available in the US."  but you can mount a Compute Engine VM on a near region to your bucket, this approach might solve the issue